# Sorting the following probability distributions from lowest to highest entropy

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to order 4 dictionary lists from lowest to highest and I am invalid syntax (I am new to bioinformatics)

I have tried inline sorting

```
lists = sorted(list_dct.items, key=lambda k: k['name'])
list_dct = [{'name': 0.5, 0, 0, 0.5},
        {'name' : 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25},
        {'name' : 0, 0, 0, 1},
        {'name' : 0.25, 0, 0.5, 0.25}]

print(lists)
```

I am getting an invalid syntax message... I should get the lists sorted by row lowest to row highest

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct your dictionaries correctly. I've chosen to make the values a list. Then sort them with a list comprehension:

```
list_dct = [{'name': [0.5, 0, 0, 0.5]},
            {'name' : [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25]},
            {'name' : [0, 0, 0, 1]},
            {'name' : [0.25, 0, 0.5, 0.25]}]

sorted([ d.get('name') for d in list_dct ])
```

Answer (score 0):

1.) Define `list_dct` before the `sorted()` function, otherwise it's syntax error

2.) You want to sort whole `list_dct`, not `list_dct.items()`

3.) Make custom `key=` sorting function, where from each item we're sorting we select 'name' key.

```
list_dct = [{'name': [0.5, 0, 0, 0.5]},
        {'name' : [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25]},
        {'name' : [0, 0, 0, 1]},
        {'name' : [0.25, 0, 0.5, 0.25]}]

lists = sorted(list_dct, key=lambda k: k['name'])

from pprint import pprint
pprint(lists)
```

Prints:

```
[{'name': [0, 0, 0, 1]},
 {'name': [0.25, 0, 0.5, 0.25]},
 {'name': [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25]},
 {'name': [0.5, 0, 0, 0.5]}]
```